# Weird display issues on Edit Post screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just went to edit one of my answers and saw this:

[image: Screen Shot]

So... I think this one speaks for itself, I'm not exactly sure how to describe what's happening.

**Code blue!**

**Note:** This only happens when you edit an *answer*.  *Questions* seem to be immune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fixed to me.

edit: ok, now it is really fixed in the next deployment.

Comment: It's not.  I just checked it; still repro.  Firefox 3.6.10.

Comment: @aaro ah, editing answers. OK.